# Turn an alarm notification on and off with buttons

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, xcode4.3

I am creating a clock app with a single alarm.

I have a button to set the alarm, a button to turn the alarm on, and a button to turn the alarm off.

The set button works using a local notification:

```
UILocalNotification *scheduledAlert;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
scheduledAlert = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
scheduledAlert.applicationIconBadgeNumber=1;
scheduledAlert.fireDate = alarmPicker.date;
scheduledAlert.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
scheduledAlert.repeatInterval =  NSDayCalendarUnit;
scheduledAlert.soundName=@"alarm_clock_ringing.wav";
scheduledAlert.alertBody = @"I’d like to get your attention again!";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]
                   scheduleLocalNotification:scheduledAlert];
```

Everything works just fine.

However, I do not know how to code the On and Off buttons.

Answer (score 0):

For the Off button you have to use something like `CancelAllCurrentNotifications`.

Comment: I would really advise against CancelAllCurrentNotifications, please check out this article: http://weblog.bignerdranch.com/780-notifications-part-3-gotchas/